# How to match braces in a document with regex?

Tags: regex

I use VSCODE 1.41.1 to edit a *MediaWiki formatted article* with lots of *MediaWiki template calls*, such as:

```
{{SOME_TEMPLATE|SOME_ARGUMNET}}
```

I want to match all `{{` and `}}` brace pairs in that document.

I Have tried:

```
[{{], [}}]
```

Interesting for me to note that `[{{]` works, but only for matching a given single pair (yet I need both pairs in one operation).

How to match braces in a document with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[{{]` is a character class that matches an opening brace or ... an opening brace! It is **strictly** equal to `[{]` or, depending on your regex flavor, a simple `{`. Same for `[}}]`.

A direct matching alternative is:  `[{]{2}|[}][2}`

Comment: The '{2}' is quantifier, that matches 2 of preceding, in this case 2 '{' characters.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I found this solution which seems to work fine:

```
[{{]|[}}]
```

Comment: `[{{]` is a character class that matches an opening brace or an opening brace! It is **strictly** equal to `[{]` or, depending on your regex flavor, `{`. Same for `[}}]`, Use `[{]{2}|[}][2}`

Comment: Hello @Toto ; I understand your point and I like your comment, thank you ; if you publish this is an answer I will gladly accept and up vote.

Comment: I've made this comment an answer.